# Implementing a table on ipad - possible solutions

Tags: uitableview, ipad

I want to implement a table which is similar to the tv guide that you see in Yahoo app on iPad. The user needs to be able to scroll horizontally, vertically and even diagonally. The cells have to be resized dynamically based on the content.
Is this possible using UITableView or AQGridView? Or is there any other other approach to implement this kind of an interface?

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve such behavior using a rotated UITableView inside a UITableView
have a look at this tutorial:

http://www.raywenderlich.com/4723/how-to-make-an-interface-with-horizontal-tables-like-the-pulse-news-app-part-2